# How Stirling numbers of first kind add to $n!$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I have a very basic doubt here.

How actually is

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n{S_1(n,k)} = n!$$?

For example, if we have a string 'ABCDEF', its permutation be 'BACDEF' and which cycle is this representing. Since if we are assuming it to be [AB][CDEF] then it is not counted differently in a cycle. I don't understand how to visualize this sum.

Comment: Stirling numbers of the first kind count how many permutations in $S_n$ have $k$ cycles in their decomposition. It is pretty trivial that *any* permutation in $S_n$ can be decomposed as a product of at most $n$ disjoint cycles.

Comment: Is $S_2$ supposed to be stirling numbers of the first kind? The suffix $2$ seems odd.

Comment: If you want to follow the canonical bijection between permutations and their cyclic decompositions, $ABCDEF$ refers to $[A][B][C][D][E][F]$ while $BACDEF$ refers to $[AB][C][D][E][F]$, they are correctly counted differently.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay I got it. So, my question was wrong. I didn't know how to represent a permutation in this decomposition and got confused.

Answer (score 4):

The Stirling number of the first kind $s(n,k)$ counts the number
of permutations in $S_n$ with $k$ cycles. So $\sum_k s(n,k)$
counts all permutations in $S_n$; of course there are $n!$ of them.